# CoffeeScript + Vue.js, Vue instance doesn't get mounted on html element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, coffeescript

I recently started developing an app with CoffeeScript, but while trying to get it to work with Vue, I quickly run into trouble. Namely, Vue instance is working, I can introspect it through developer console, but it doesn't get binded to DOM element, even though I tried it both by specyfing `"el"` attribute on instance and using `$mount` method on it. Heres my main.coffee:

```
import Vue from "vue"

app = new Vue
  el: "#app" 
  data:
    n: 42

console.log app #so I can introspect it in console
# as webpack apparently does some sort of name mangling
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">Answer to the Ultimate Question of Everything: {{ n }}</div>
  <script src="./dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "coffee-app",
  "devDependencies": {
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "coffeescript": "^2.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.17"
  }
}
```

And finally my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry:  __dirname + "/main.coffee",
  output: {
    filename: "main.bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.coffee?$/,
        use: "coffee-loader",
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

So, unfortunately, template doesn't get rendered (div element is even not created at all). I noticed also that instance `$el` attribute has very strange value: it's a function, instead of DOM element (checked with Firefox and Chrome, this behaviour is the same for both). How is it possible? How should I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default webpack version of vue only includes the vue runtime, not the template compiler.

To check, you can write your own render method (which the compiler normally generates at compile time)

```
app = new Vue
  el: "#app" 
  data:
    n: 42
  render: (h) -> h("h1", "Hello")
```

If you can't compile all templates at compile time, use the compiled-included build by editing your webpack.config.js:

```
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to include template compiler, while working with vue from npm and webpack (So I could avoid these "react-like" renders)?

Comment: Yes, i've updated my answer to include the webpack modification you need to make.